# How to convert nested objects into nested DTOs using ModelMapper?

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I am facing issue when I am trying to use ModelMapper to convert nested java objects into nested DTO's. Getting null for child dto's in parent dto object. Following are the code snippets.

**Entity Classes :**

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    private Product product;
}

public class Address { 
    private String area;
    private String city;
}

public class Product {
    private Integer productId;
    private String productName;
    private Double productPrice;
 }
```

**DTO's Classes :**

```
public class UserDTO {
   private String name;
   private AddressDTO address;
   private ProductDTO product;
}

public class AddressDTO {
   private String area;
   private String city;
}

public class ProductDTO {
   private Integer productId;
   private String productName;
   private Double productPrice;
}
```

**here is the mapper code :**

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
UserDTO userDTO = mapper.map(user, UserDTO.class);
System.out.println("Output User DTO : " + userDTO );
```

**Output :**

**Output User DTO : UserDTO [name=xyz, address=null, product=null]**

Here I want to convert User entity into UserDTO dto.
I am getting null values for address and product DTO's. What exactly I am missing here ? Does anyone have any idea ?

*Note : I have added getters, Setters and toString() methods in entity and DTO's.*

Comment: It seems like your DTO is a duplication of Entity. Duplication is always  evil. Would you really like to apply this pattern? or just remain one of them?

Comment: Right now in my case both Entity's and DTO's are the same but eventually DTO's will have some extra fields than entities. So currently I am focusing on object conversion part with model mapper.

Comment: How does it behave when you use the standard MatchingStrategy?

Comment: @Smile , Getting null for referenced fields (for address & product) in userDTO with standard MatchingStrategy.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found solution for nested DTO to Entity and vice versa conversions, I was missing some ModelMapper configurations that I have added below.

```
mapper.getConfiguration()
      .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
      .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
      .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STANDARD);
```